# set global one component vue for use anywhere

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm working whit laravel and I have installed component vue.  https://github.com/dalphyx/vue-top-progress

I will like to use this component into different pages and other components.

I don't know how to set global, for use other components or pages blade. laravel.

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('crud1', require('./components/crud1.vue').default);
Vue.component('crud2', require('./components/crud2.vue').default);


import { vueTopprogress } from 'vue-top-progress';


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    mounted(){
        this.$refs.topProgress.start()
        setTimeout(() => {
        this.$refs.topProgress.done()
      }, 2000)

    },

    components: {
      vueTopprogress
    }
        
});
```

home.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper" id="app">
        <vue-topprogress ref="topProgress"></vue-topprogress>

        <crud1></crud1>
    </div>
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

crud1.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">crud 1 Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.$refs.topProgress.start()
            setTimeout(() => {
               this.$refs.topProgress.done()
            }, 2000)
        }
    }
```

if I use `"this.$refs.topProgress.start()"` on crud1 I get this error

```
app.js:41686 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined"

found in

---> <crud1> at resources/js/components/crud1.vue
       <Root>
```

Comment: simply set the color `<vue-topprogress color="#000"></vue-topprogress>`

Comment: And further to @Aslam 's answer, if you use it in a component, and want color to be customizable, then add the color as a prop to the parent component and when you use it in your component, <vue-topprogress :color="color"></vue-top-progress>

Comment: it's ok props, but how can I use this component global, to a different place, page or other components, if I use on crud1. error `Cannot read property 'start' of undefined`